# Error: The getter 'hellawait' isn't defined for the class 'IOClient'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I created and run a location and weather based app. But when I closed the VS Code and try to reinstall the app, the following error occurred!.
How to remove the error!.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X655C in debug mode...
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/io_client.dart:35:34: Error: Expected ')' before this.
      var ioRequest = (hellawait _inner!.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
                                 ^^^^^^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/io_client.dart:35:24: Error: The getter 'hellawait' isn't defined for the class 'IOClient'.
- 'IOClient' is from 'package:http/src/io_client.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.13.4/lib/src/io_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'hellawait'.
      var ioRequest = (hellawait _inner!.openUrl(request.method, request.url))
                       ^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: You've somehow accidentally modified the code in your `.pub-cache` directory (maybe via an errant global search/replace?).  I suggest removing `C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\http-0.13.4` and re-running `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 1):

I know its a bit ago, but

```bash
flutter pub cache repair
```

helped me